# Why is the reason given by me when voting to close misrepresented?

Tags: discussion

Take a look at the closure notice below the question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/106093/how-to-create-an-image-gallery-album-like-facebook

It says: "marked as duplicate by ..., Gisle Hannemyr".

However, I *never* marked this as duplicate.  I voted to close, but with "unclear what you're asking" as the reason.

I understand that the *majority* of those who voted to close marked it is duplicate.  I happen to think the majority made a bad judgement in this particular case, but understand that this is the majority's prerogative.

But it bugs me that I am included in the list of people that made that bad judgement.

I think this needs to fixed. If one does not want the closure message to become too verbose (by spelling out who voted for what), then only the names of those that voted with the majority's reason to be should be explicitly named.

Comment: "album like facebook = Facebook like photo gallery" it looks completely dupe for me and I'm not sure why its unclear to you.

Comment: @bala, I did not start post to discuss *why* this particular question was closed, so I see no point in trying to explain *why* I see this particular one different than you.  I just wanted to know if the misrepresentation of my vote was by design, or a caused by some random error. MPD has already answered that.  (I am however, puzzled by the downvotes on this one, but I can live with that as well.)

Comment: @GisleHannemyr The downvotes are odd, this seems a perfectly valid question with a perfectly valid answer. Perhaps people read it (incorrectly) as looking for a discussion on the question's closure in the first place. If any downvoters stop by again, it would be great to hear why you disagree with this/don't feel it's a reasonable question/etc

Comment: @GisleHannemyr Downvoting on meta is different (and broken, IMHO).  Sometimes voting means agree/disagree.  Sometime it means good/bad question.  I suspect some disagree that the question isn't a dup and/or that there is a misrepresentation.

Comment: @Clive I guess the question got down-voted because users are not worried to be included in the list of users who voted to close the question for the reason chosen by the majority. That would mean "you are raising a point where there is nothing to talk of."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the close vote reason chosen from the majority is the one that is displayed (or in a tie, the last one cast).  There has been a feature request for this, but it has not been implemented.

In general, the exact close reason doesn't matter too much, as questions are initially put on hold so that the user has a chance to edit it into something better. However, I do agree with you that this is misleading in the case of disagreement over whether something is a duplicate or not.

#### References

- [What happens if a fifth person chooses a different reason to close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32700/what-happens-if-a-fifth-person-chooses-a-different-reason-to-close)
- [Priority of Close Votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39658/priority-of-close-votes)
- [Distinguish close votes by reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-votes-to-close-by-reason)
- [What is a "closed" or “on hold” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time researching this.  I am glad to hear that a request to fix this bug exists.  To ensure that the site's quality standards are upheld, bad questions need to be closed, and to close, members need to have an incentive to vote. To risk having one's vote publicly misrepresented is a huge *disincentive* when one consider whether to vote or not.